# Is it possible to get a value from jsp page while clicking links in the menu

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I have page called menu.jsp which contain links and another jsp name Page1.jsp.

I want to get the page1.jsp's text box/label value while clicking the any link in menu.jsp. How to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using **application scope** in JSP.

> A JSP object created using the ‘application’ scope can be accessed
>   from any pages across the application.

In simple terms,

Set your variable/value into application scope within jsp page1.
  And get it from application scope in jsp page2.

Please refer this page for a [**complete example**](https://www.dineshonjava.com/jsp-scopes-example/):